# How to create such a unit in flexbox?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, flexbox

Good evening, I would like to know how to create such a block as in the picture? To pictures of how coca-cola and Adidas was on the left side of the block and the other blocks were..

[picture of layout in 768px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgtyP.jpg)

and looked to 480 pixels:

[picture of layout in 480px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wI7X.jpg)

Comment: Questions seeking help ("why isn't, or how to make, this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

You can create that kind of blocks by using CSS grids. There is a really good tutorial about it, which will show you how you can create such boxes just in half an hour. Visit this youTube video tutotial to learn about it.
CSS Grid Layout Crash Course
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV8B24rSN5o
Hope this helps.